# How to return raw XML from a fetch request?

Tags: node.js, xml, fetch-api

I have to retrieve XML data from a server. I'm using Fetch since I need an async/await compatible way of making HTTP requests.

However using resp.text() when retrieving the data via fetch causes it to escape all quotes and newlines.

Here's what the result should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <value var_id="v04" xsi:type="ELEMENT">hello</value>
</data>
```

And here's what it actually looks like:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><data xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n      <value var_id=\"v04\" xsi:type=\"ELEMENT\">hello</value>\n</data>\n"
```

Anyway I can prevent this and receive the raw XML? Alternatively, anyway to parse it back to its original form? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use Postman to double-check? You should be getting the same results there

Comment: That's not actually escaped - it's just printing it escaped in your console when you look at the text so you can copy/paste it :]

Comment: I checked with CURL. It's definitely enclosing the entire thing in double quotes and escaping the quotes within the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing `.text` in node-fetch just does:

```
    return consumeBody.call(this).then(buffer => buffer.toString());
```

<sub>This is literally the source code of .text</sub>

Which is just a Node [`Buffer#toString()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) - that does no escaping one way or another.

Node.js does escape strings before printing them so you can use them and copy-paste them.

Rest assured - this is just a UI visibility feature - not an actual text escaping change :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. It turns out it was the JSON.stringify function later on in the code that's was stringifying it.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, JSON.stringify does that. If this answer solved your issue please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yeah, just waiting 3 minutes to accept it. Thanks.